# p4 submit -r with leaveunchanged

Tags: perforce

P4 2015.2/1264740
I would like to keep a bunch of files as opened for edit as I work. Once I want to submit some changes, I want the changed files to be submitted and reopened, and I want the unchanged files to be left alone. I've tried with p4 submit -r -f leaveunchanged, but that ignores the -r switch - so the submitted files are not reopened. Using p4 submit -r without -f uses my default of revertunchanged which has the opposite effect of reverting all non-changed files.
How do I get this to work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want `p4 submit -f submitunchanged+reopen`

Comment: Thanks! I use leaveunchanged+reopen which works perfectly.